# How to add the username and passwords to a request in java spring

Tags: java, spring, http, security

I'm currently trying to add security to my spring application and just want to know how can i add the credentials to the request so that it has the security access to access the getall URL
This is the post code on my client aplication

```
    public void save(String object) {
    try {
        final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/opject/getall";
        Gson g = new Gson();
        String jsonsStrinjg = g.toJson(object);
        String p = post(URL, jsonsStrinjg);
        if (p != null)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucsess");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fail");


    }catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
}

public String post(final String url, String json) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    try(Response response= client.newCall(request).execute()){
        return response.body().string();

    }

}
```

This is the code on my server side handling security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("Admin")
          .password(encoder().encode("123"))
          .roles("ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"**/getall").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder(){

    return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();


}
```

}
So is there something I have to add tot he body or the request where i can add the password and username.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Basic Auth to your header which will look like,

```
Authorization: Basic <base64encode(userid:password)>
```

To achieve that,

```
String auth = username + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
```

Then set the `authHeader` to http header when you call api.